# Flexible approach to grouping and displaying data using gt or flextable

Tags: r, flextable, gt

I have two sets of data; one with counts of "X" per age-group and one with counts of "Y" per age-group.

```
# Data frames
dataX <- data.frame(
  "ID" = 1:6,
  "X_0_to_2" = c(58, 58, 46, 98, 43, 39),
  "X_3_to_5" = c(47, 34, 51, 95, 29, 66),
  "X_6_to_8" = c(81, 95, 97, 79, 49, 63),
  "X_9_to_11" = c(34, 71, 39, 70, 41, 13),
  "X_12_to_14" = c(50, 75, 35, 67, 92, 61)
)

dataY <- data.frame(
  "ID" = 1:6,
  "Y_0_to_2" = c(85, 20, 58, 77, 30, 92),
  "Y_3_to_5" = c(42, 96, 63, 10, 58, 77),
  "Y_6_to_8" = c(88, 40, 17, 82, 58, 10),
  "Y_9_to_11" = c(55, 69, 38, 53, 15, 49),
  "Y_12_to_14" = c(22, 73, 92, 78, 41, 20)
)
```

I want to display them like this:

```
      Age 0-2     Age 3-5  ...    Total
      X     Y  |  X     Y  ...   X     Y
ID |           |           ...
1  | 58    85  | 47    42  ... 105   127
2  | 58    20  | 34    96  ...  92   116
3  | 46    58  | 51    63  ...  97   121
```

I can somewhat achieve my desired result by merging, sorting and naming the columns manually and using  `gt::tab_spanner()`, but that solution is not really flexible. I suspect there is an easier way I just haven't come across, yet.

Solutions using `gt` or `flextable` are equally welcome.

Update: data in a tidy format:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L), X_Y = c("X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", 
"Y", "X", "Y"), `0_to_2` = c(58, 85, 58, 20, 46, 58, 98, 77, 
43, 30, 39, 92), `3_to_5` = c(47, 42, 34, 96, 51, 63, 95, 10, 
29, 58, 66, 77), `6_to_8` = c(81, 88, 95, 40, 97, 17, 79, 82, 
49, 58, 63, 10), `9_to_11` = c(34, 55, 71, 69, 39, 38, 70, 53, 
41, 15, 13, 49), `12_to_14` = c(50, 22, 75, 73, 35, 92, 67, 78, 
92, 41, 61, 20), Total = c(270, 292, 333, 298, 268, 268, 409, 
300, 254, 202, 242, 248)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you share the code that gets you your _somewhat_ solution? Also what exactly do you mean by flexible.

Comment: can you share the data before it is split in two data.frame, in a tidy format?

Comment: @DavidGohel I added tidy data! :-)

Comment: @Mark: that’s not a tidy data frame - there is information in the column names.

Comment: you're right @Limey, but I opted not to turn the age range column names into columns, given the desired output of OP. You're welcome to change it though

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `tabulator()`. But it expects a tidy format (your examples are not tidy so it needs to be transformed first to work with your data).

```
library(flextable)
library(tidyr)

dat <- pivot_longer(df, cols = -c(ID, X_Y))

tabulator(
  x = dat,
  rows = "ID",
  columns = c("name", "X_Y"),
  blah = as_paragraph(as_chunk(value, formatter = fmt_int))
) |> as_flextable()
```

[image]